# CSS image button link resize

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make an image button that links to my site.
Link is working good, but my image is appearing wrong.

```css
.dugme {
  background-image: url("logo.png");
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  right: 100px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <a href="strana1.html"><button type="submit" class="dugme"></button></a>
</body>
```

This is the expected output:

[image: expected]

This is the output:

[image: result]

THANK YOU !

Comment: Is the img in the same folder like your html-file?

Comment: Yes, everything is fine. Image is in the same folder and CSS file too.

Comment: If Image in correct place.. Issue with image size.. button size you are restricting to 40px but image size is bigger.. add     background-size: contain; Or resize image to button size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your logo is too big for the button. Just try to use `background-size: contain` to resize the image to fit it into your button.

> Contain:  Resize the background image to make sure the image is fully visible

- [CSS background-size Property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp)

```css
.dugme {
    background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUvD1.png");
    background-size: 165%;
    background-position: 45% 53%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    right: 100px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <a href="strana1.html"><button type="submit" class="dugme"></button></a>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Patrick, I really appreciate this effort from you !

Comment: I've updated it with your icon so it's centered and round.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following CSS code and share your reviews

```
       .dugme{
        border-radius:100%;
        background-image: url("logo.png");
        background-color:transparent;
        background-size:cover;
        background-position:center;
        border-width:0px;
        outline:none;
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        }
```

Comment: This seems to be the closest answer to my expected output.
This is how it looks like: http://prntscr.com/hta0yo

Comment: Yes, this is how it looks like: http://prntscr.com/hta0yo
image seems to be out of the center, but it is acceptable

Comment: have you used any padding ?

Comment: Yes, but it didn't help. Thank you so much for your effort.

Comment: Try background-position:center; can you post snippet ? jsfiddle? so that i can able to answer clearly

Comment: Check this: https://jsfiddle.net/pradeep0594/9qz6vocu/    Since the image was not available i have used random image. You just replace the image with your image

Comment: That is it, this is what I wanted ! Thank you man  !! You really helped me.

Comment: you are welcome pal.. If you satisfied, Just accept my answer :)

Comment: how can I do that ? I'm sry but this is my first time here !

Comment: upvote on it You will have an option with tick mark . Press on it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
.dugme {
    background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUvD1.png") no-repeat center center;
    background-size: contain;
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    right: 100px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <a href="strana1.html"><button type="submit" class="dugme"></button></a>
</body>
```

To make the background to be contained inside button and the background image doesn't repeat

Comment: I've copied that code and it outputs like this :http://prntscr.com/ht9yn3

Comment: Try background-size:cover;

Comment: @HarunDurak Can you check my answer and share your reviews ?